# How to save a related, inline django model when parent is saved in the admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-signals

In my models, I have an `Event` class, a `Volunteer` class, and a `Session` class. The Session class has a foreign key field for an Event and a Volunteer, and is a unique coupling of both, as well as a date and time. Taken together, Volunteer and Event I think technically have a ManyToMany relationship.

Using the pre-packaged Django admin, I edit Volunteers and Events with their own `admin.ModelAdmin` classes respectively. Sessions are edited inline in the Events `ModelAdmin`.

When I add a new Session to an event in the admin interface, with a Volunteer, I need the Volunteer's `hours` field to be automatically updated, to reflect however many hours the newly added session lasted (plus all past sessions). Currently, I just have a `calculate_hours` function in the `Volunteer` model, which iterates over all sessions each time it is called and finds the sum of the hours. I tried to call it with a custom save function in Session, but it appears never to be called after the Event save function. I would try it in Event, but I have no way to isolate which Volunteers need their hours recalculated. The hours field IS updated if I manually go over to the Volunteer admin page, edit, and then save the Volunteer, but this is pretty unacceptable.

I see that there are many questions on SO about Django problems when saving inline objects on the admin site, particularly with ManyToMany fields. I'm not sure, after reading many of these questions, if what they say applies in my case--maybe I need to receive a signal somewhere, or include a custom save in a special place, or call `save_model` in my `admin.ModelAdmin` class... I just don't know. What is the best way to go about this?

Code can be found here: [Models.py](https://github.com/bepetersn/townsquare2/blob/master/square/models.py), [Admin.py](https://github.com/bepetersn/townsquare2/blob/master/square/admin.py)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the relationship you're describing is what called a ManyToMany "through" (you can read about it in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)).

Secondly, I don't understand why you need the 'hours' to be a field at all. Isn't a function enough for this? why save it in the database in the first place? you can just call it every time you need it.

Finally, it seems to me you're doing a lot of extra work that I don't understand - why do you need the volunteer time boolean field? If you link a volunteer with an event isn't that enough to know that he was there? And what's the purpose of "counts_towards_volunteer_time"? I'm probably missing some of the logic here, but a lot of that seems wasteful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I need to explicitly define a `ManyToManyField` on  my Event class? Up til now I was just using the related fields like `Event.session_set` to get all of my data and it appeared to work. Except for this saving thing. 

Honestly, I was hoping the hours field would eventually allow me to not iterate over every session every time, since the data that I'm working with has some volunteers with a long history. I initially had it set up to just call the function, though.

The `volunteer_time` field represents whether or not a session gets counted towards the `hours`.

Comment: You don't have to explicitly define it but there are some advantages to it (query-wise). As for the "hours" field, I still don't understand why you want to save it in the database. You can just use the function (if you want to do a query just do it in list comprehension: [v.calc_hours() for v in Volunteer.objects.all() ]

Comment: Right, but say a volunteer has a 1000 sessions associated with them. Why iterate over every session any time a single session is saved? I could possibly instead just add the value of the session's length to the already stored value of the hours, and not have to do all that legwork each time.

Comment: I'm gonna try re-organizing session as a ManyToMany "through" field right now. I'm dubious, but perhaps it will solve my saving problems.

Comment: I think you are right about some of this stuff being too complex in my models.

Comment: Even if there are 10,000 entries, you still want to calculate it each time. Trust me, it won't take as long as you think it would, and it makes a lot more sense than doing the workaround to needlessly save it in the DB

Comment: Well, for now I'm still saving it in the DB AND calculating every time. This project is still in its early phase, so the redundancy will be sorted out eventually. Actually, the reason is pretty simple. I want the admin interface to work right now, and the simplest way I can see to do it is by having a non-editable, read-only field to display. I was looking at your answer here: stackoverflow.com/a/18080029/1151229. Perhaps I will create my own django template to replace this eventually. That's certainly in the works. But I want basic functionality first.

Comment: Also, I solved my saving problem by the most direct means. The session save function was being called, but what I needed updated was the volunteer's hours field. In the session's custom save, after the actual saving, I now include a call to `self.volunteer.save()`.

Comment: As the python zen goes, simple is better than complex. By the way, when you decide to expand the project, look for a package called django-dilla. It's ment for spamming your database. I don't have any experience with it but it should be a great way to test how queries like your calc_hours deal with large number of entries